# What is the earliest time I can use findViewById in a View subclass?

Tags: android, layout

I have custom View I've written that hooks up a series of buttons to predefined methods. These buttons are children of the View I'm creating.

My question is, what's the earliest method I can use to override to use a series of `findViewById`'s? I believe I can't use it in the constructor, as any calls to `findViewById` will return `null`.

Thanks,

Brad.

Comment: If the view hierarchy is not complicated, maybe it is possible to loop through the children and compare the id in the constructor, though I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your class is a sub class of `ViewGroup`, you can override `onFinishInflate` and use `findViewById` inside this method:

```
public void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_id);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The earliest you can access children through `findViewById` is immediately after inflating a layout.

```
inflator.inflate(R.layout.main, this);
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to findViewById in side your custom view [onAttachedToWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow%28%29) may be a good place this may be useful to set any listener, but if you want only in other override methods I mostly go something like below:

```
View mView;

View getView(){
     if(mView==null){
         mView=findViewById(...);
     }
     return mView;
}
```